# Handeling exception (etrepat/baum) in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and the Baum class (https://github.com/etrepat/baum). Great class by the way!

There is a method to move a sibling to the left or right (https://github.com/etrepat/baum#moving-nodes). If it is not possible to move a sibling because it is already the most left (or right) the class throws an error.

> MoveNotPossibleException in Move.php line 206: Could not resolve
>   target node. This node cannot move any further to the left.

https://github.com/etrepat/baum/blob/master/src/Baum/MoveNotPossibleException.php

Now the question: How do I handle this?
I tried:

```
$item = Auth::user()->application->items->find($id);
try {
    $item->moveLeft();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return 'Move not possible';
}
```

But this does not seem to work. I am new with exceptions so probably I am doing something fundamentally wrong that does not have anything to do with this specific class. I still would like to make it work :)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
catch (Exception $e)
```

with

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

When you do it the first way, without providing fully qualified class name, you're catching exceptions of **Current\Namespace\Exception** class.